# What do to with the [apm] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The [tag wiki of the APM tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apm/info) currently reads:

> APM generally refers to Application Performance Management. The best in class tools provide real-time access to detailed information about the performance of a system and its components (including transaction tracing, database and external system response times, etc.)

There is no real tag wiki yet, so the description is just a stub. [The questions on the APM tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apm) do not follow that definition. Instead, APM in these questions is used to refer to at least the following four topics

- Application Performance Management (the "correct" one)
- Asynchronous Programming Model
- A Linux command to query Advanced Power Management (APM) BIOS
- The Atom Package Manager

Since we are a programming site, I'd suggest to rebrand APM as Asynchronous Programming Model, because questions about Application Performance Management are usually about tools and likely Off Topic. Questions about the Linux command are better suited for a sister site: Unix & Linux, AskUbuntu or even Superuser and the Atom Package Manager could live under atom. No need to have a separate tag for that.

What do you think?

Comment: In 8 years, it managed to have 59 questions, and none of the top answerers have more than 2 answers... it's really needed?

Comment: @Braiam it's certainly not urgent. But you know… OCD and stuff :)

Comment: APM isn't *just* a Linux command. It's an important architectural feature that you're going to have to deal with if you write an OS or want to interface with hardware at a low level. Thus, I don't think altogether ignoring Advanced Power Management, or assuming there are no on-topic questions about it, is sensible.